# Should a pen be light or heavy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life

Expensive pens are usually heavy. Naturally a heavy weight is not expected for an ordinary pen.

But in the view of mechanics, the more the inertia the more the capability of holding the speed. Is then the reason for making pens heavy?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about second-guessing design decisions.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the reason for such weight is material that is used, just like in jewelry.

But that doesn't mean that weight can be completely ignored. The important part is weight distribution, so that the center of mass is closer to the top of the pen.

Also, important thing is the grip that pen has, and the quality of the nib, as well as the ink.

So my answer is basically no; inertia and mass have nothing to do with quality of a pen.

Comment: I do not totally agree. I can image that a pen with a larger inertia/mass would react less intense to small disturbances in the hand movements , reducing the effect on the writing quality?

Comment: @ROIMaison I think that only starts to play a role for a pen heavier than hand+wrist+arm.

Comment: Why's that? I don't think all excitations are executed with the hand+wrist+arm combination. If there's an unwanted  jitter in your finger, the difference between the two masses might be quite small.